# mongodb replica setup: not authorized on local to execute command

Tags: mongodb

I've been following this guide: https://gist.github.com/calvinh8/c99e198ce5df3d8b1f1e42c1b984d7a4

I just finished setting up all my servers and created the user in the admin database giving this return:

```
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "user",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I am trying to link up the databases with the command:

`rs.add("ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com")`

But it gives me back the error:

```
2018-04-11T00:20:56.389+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: count failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on local to execute command { count: \"system.replset\", query: {}, fields: {} }",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBQuery.prototype.count@src/mongo/shell/query.js:383:11
DBCollection.prototype.count@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1700:12
rs.add@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:1240:1
@(shell):1:1
```

Is there some login I need to do for authentication when pointing to the replica? Do I have the keyFile wrong between machines? Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: After adding the user, have you tried **authenticating as the user** ? Or are you still connected without authentication?

Comment: Do i need to authenticate as the user to add a replica?

Comment: Once the server is running with authentication enabled, then you need to authenticate your connection to do **anything**.

Comment: `db.auth("user", "XXXXXXXXXX")` everything worked from there on out, including adding replicas and the admin database was copied to SECONDARY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide you're following is not very helpful; it misses out the crucial step that you **need to authenticate your connection**, once you've created that first admin user.

I suggest that you read the official MongoDB docs about [authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/security/) and [replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/) (both are comprehensive and well-written); in particular, the [guide to enabling authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) covers precisely the situation you found yourself in.

Answer (score 3):

I find the "comprehensive and well-written" documentation referred in another answer here quite confusing and misleading when one just needs to set up a database. However, this official tutorial is almost on the target: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-keyfile-access-control/#deploy-repl-set-with-auth

This got to be simple, and it is: install bare dbs, create the key and place it on each box, update the configs, start each db, get on the one designated as primary locally, start the replicaset from the mongoshell. One issue I had is that all replicaset members have to be added in one shot (as suggested in the tutorial). Otherwise, after adding the 1st member, the authentication requirement kicks in and prevents from adding more members till a cluster admin user is created. So, after starting the replicaset and before leaving the shell, make sure to create 3 users: admin, cluster admin and backup admin, check the ability to login from another shell, and then continue working under the proper user

Comment: thanks for your comment. experience speaking.. Indeed before you can add members you should create a clusteradmin and then authenticate using db.auth('user','pass'), after that you can add members using rs.add('ip:27017') .